# The name 'DataList1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I get the following error in a page:

> 'The name 'DataList1' does not exist in the current context'

Here is my code:

**listviewvideo.aspx.cs**

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from uploadvideo";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataList1.DataBind();
               con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**listviewvideo.aspx**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo ID="FlashVideo1" runat="server" Height="500" Width="1050"></ASPNetFlashVideo:FlashVideo>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnupload_Click" CssClass="myButton" />
    <hr />
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Visible="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RepeatColumns="2" CellSpacing="5">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <u>
    <%# Eval("Name") %>
    </u>
    <a class="player" style="height:300px; width:300px; display:block" href='<%# Eval("Id","FileCS.ashx?Id={0}") %>'></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I get the following error in a page:

> 'The name 'DataList1' does not exist in the current context'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get this error. There 3 solutions for this

- 1. Save your project and close the Solution, close the `IIS Express` also. And check whether it works or not.
- 2. Try adding the the datalist by writing below code in your `listviewvideo.aspx.designer.cs` page of where you are adding the `Datalist` item.
- 3. Check your code behind file name and Inherits property on the `@Page` directive, make sure they both match.

Also you can have a look here for more clear picture

[ID Does not exist in the current context](http://www.ajaymatharu.com/the-name-does-not-exists-in-the-current-context-asp-net/)

```html
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList Datalist1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time, listviewvideo.aspx.designer.cs is missing in my project..? what to do?

Comment: @DeepakRatan: Which version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: @DeepakRatan: Also see the `third` point of my answer. Hope it might help you

Comment: visual studio 2012 ultimate, <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="listviewvideo.aspx.cs" Inherits="listviewvideo" %>  there is no problem in your third point

Comment: @DeepakRatan: Add your CS code in the http://jsfiddle.net/ and send the link of both the page